# Does a tight apartness relation on a subobject classifier imply the elementary topos is Boolean?

Tags: set-theory, topos-theory, constructive-mathematics

Given a set $S$, a tight apartness relation on $S$ is a relation $\#$ which is tight, irreflexive, symmetric, and weakly linear, or more specifically, a relation $\#$ such that

- for all elements $a \in S$ and $b \in S$, $a = b$ if and only if $\neg a \# b$
- for all elements $a \in S$, $\neg a \# a$
- for all elements $a \in S$ and $b \in S$, $a \# b$ implies that $b \# a$
- for all elements $a \in S$, $b \in S$, and $c \in S$, $a \# c$ implies that $a \# b$ or $b \# c$.

Assume that the category of sets is an elementary topos. This means that it contains a subobject classifier $\Omega$.

If the category of sets is Boolean, the subobject classifier $\Omega$ automatically has a tight apartness relation given by negation of equality, because in such a case, $\Omega$ is just the set with two elements and thus has decidable equality.

Is the converse of the above statement true? Namely, if $\Omega$ has a tight apartness relation $\#$, then is the category of sets Boolean?

Comment: IIRC the results in the "propositions-as-some-types" part of my article [Apartness relations between propositions](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.03920) apply to the  intuitionistic higher-order logic of topoi pretty much verbatim. In particular, whenever $\#$ is an irreflexive relation on $\Omega$, the implications $\top \# P \rightarrow \neg P$ and $\bot \# P \rightarrow \neg\neg P$ hold, and as Mike proved in his answer, the existence of a tight, irreflexive relation on $\Omega$ implies the law of excluded middle.

Comment: BTW, tightness stated as an if-and-only-if, as in the question, implies irreflexivity: since $a=a$ we have $\neg a\#a$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.  The tightness axiom, $(a=b)\iff \neg (a\#b)$, implies
$$\neg\neg(a=b) \iff \neg\neg\neg(a\#b) \iff \neg(a\#b) \iff (a=b).$$
Taking $b=\top$, we find that $\neg\neg a \iff a$ for all $a: \Omega$.  This is the law of double negation, which is equivalent to excluded middle.